# How fix error design Edittext

Tags: android, android-layout

I design with android 4.0.3: theme.holo
When i change back color of edittext,It show lines is black color at first edittext.
How do hides black line of edittext when change background color?
Watch image: [Click Here](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-DDBRe0V3eBo/UATctb3A_ZI/AAAAAAAACZw/XCSES8RHFdY/w426-h245-k/7-17-2012+10-13-03+AM.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set android:textCursorDrawable="@null" in your layout

Answer (score 3):

you should be able to use

```
android:cursorVisible="false"
```

in your xml or

```
editTxt.setCursorVisible(false);
```

from java

**EDIT:**

Use an [OnFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html) on the EditText to get a callback when it gets and loses focus and use the setCursorVisible() method to set the cursor to whichever state you need.

Comment: if disible cursor it will hide black line but when input edittext hasn't cursor.(any way hide black line but cursor still has when input?)

Comment: you should be able to use setCursorVisible() method in conjuction with a onFocusChange listener to set it to the appropriate value when the EditText has focus. (see my edit)